# Cannot INSERT strings with Set Clause with mariadb connector (python)

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I want to insert a new row in my table by using the python-mariadb connector. For that I prefer to use the SET clause.
For some reason it does work if I only want to save ints (i.e y=2), but when I use a string, the following error occurs

> Unknown column 'myString' in 'field list'

It seems it thinks the content of the string is a column name? Any idea how to fix that (I can do it with INSERT INTO ... VALUES ..., but I want to use the SET clause here). From my understanding, it should save both an int and a str without throwing an error
Thank you.

See the code example below

```
def myfunction():
    x = 1
    y ='myString'
    db = connect_db()
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO Table SET col1={}, col2={}"
    cur.execute(sql.format(x, y))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return
```

Here the MariaDB Connector, but this should be fine as it works for other db functions.

```
import mariadb

def connect_db():
    db = mariadb.connect(
        user="user",
        password="123",
        host="localhost",
        port=3306,
    database="DB"
    )
db.autocommit = False
return db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in question produces the SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO Table SET col1=1, col2=myString;
```

This is incorrect syntax, and strings must be in single-quotes:

```sql
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 'myString');
```

```py
def myfunction():
    x = 1
    y ='myString'
    db = connect_db()
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO Table (col1, COL2) VALUES ({}, '{}')"
    cur.execute(sql.format(x, y))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return
```

But the above is fragile. Don't use string building methods to create SQL statements, it is much better to use parameter binding.

```py
def myfunction():
    x = 1
    y ='myString'
    db = connect_db()
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)"
    cur.execute(sql, (x, y))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return
```

The MariaDB connector [documentation](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/) explains these things.

> ## Retrieving Data
>
> Once you have the initial code in place you can start working with the data. The first thing you should do is try to
> retrieve information from the database. Here is code for a query
> against the employees database:
>
> ```py
> cur.execute(
>     "SELECT first_name,last_name FROM employees WHERE first_name=?", 
>     (some_name,))
> ```
>
> MariaDB Connector/Python uses prepared statements, sanitizing and inserting the values from the tuple into the position
> of the question marks (?). This is safer than inserting through
> f-strings or format specifiers when working with user provided
> information.
>
> The query results are stored in a list in the cursor object. To view
> the results, you can loop over the cursor.
>
> ## Adding Data
>
> Using the same execute() method with an INSERT statement, you can add rows to the table.
>
> ```py
> cursor.execute(
>     "INSERT INTO employees (first_name,last_name) VALUES (?, ?)", 
>     (first_name, last_name))
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. My approach was not possible in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

you are not using right syntax for insert

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Table (col1,col2) values({}, {})"
```

but if you want to update an existing row:

```
sql = "UPDATE Table SET col1={}, col2={} WHERE id = {}"
```

and probably you need a where clause